# Execution of cmd cells in databricks notebook based on some condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I have a python 3.5 notebook in databricks. I have a requirement to execute databricks notebook cells based on some conditions. I didn't see any functionality out of the box.

I have tried creating a python egg with the below code and installed it in databricks cluster.

```
def skip(line, cell=None):
'''Skips execution of the current line/cell if line evaluates to True.'''
  if eval(line):
    return

  get_ipython().ex(cell)

def load_ipython_extension(shell):

  '''Registers the skip magic when the extension loads.'''
  shell.register_magic_function(skip, 'line_cell')

def unload_ipython_extension(shell):
  '''Unregisters the skip magic when the extension unloads.'''
  del shell.magics_manager.magics['cell']['skip']
```

But while I'm trying to load that with extension using 
    %load_ext skip_cell
it's throwing an error saying "The module is not an IPython module". Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Databricks notebooks are not based on Jupyter/IPython, which is why you are seeing that error.

If you are trying to build conditional workflows I would recommend combining the *Notebook Workflows* functionality with the Databricks REST API.  This will allow you to control the flow of your program based on conditional statements and results of other processes.

Think of a notebook as a function that can be [parameterized](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/widgets.html#widgets) to accept and return [exit values](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/dbutils.html#notebook-workflow-utilities).

For an example, see the official documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#example).

Answer (score 1):

Now there is support to run notebooks based on condition

```
if <condition>:
    dbutils.notebook.run("notebook-name", 60, {"argument": "data", "argument2": "data2", ...})
```

More details here
https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#example

Comment: the issue here would be that the %run /notebook_path/ does not need any exit command and will get all the objects/functions from the other notebook while the dbutils.notebook.run() doesn't and you explicitly need to specify the exit values

Comment: @GeorgeSotiropoulos not sure about this. But the run command works very similar to the %run and it works fine without the exit command which is optional.